# Deploy PHP application using TFS 2013 and Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, tfs

I have setup Jenkins (with Git, MSBuild,TFS modules) and TFS 2013 (for code management). I am developing PHP applications and would like to deploy the code from TFS 2013 server to various servers such as to production, using jenkins or TFS build process. Can anyone recommend a way of doing this (without upgrading to TFS 2015 as recommended by Miccrosoft team).

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on using TFS2013. You can add the `InvokeProcess` activity in build process template to execute the xcopy command line to copy files from source to destination. Please refer to the example for more details in this article: [Customize Team Build 2010 – Use more complex arguments](http://www.ewaldhofman.nl/post/2010/04/28/Customize-Team-Build-2010-e28093-Part-3-Use-more-complex-arguments.aspx)

Then add your target server name. After your queue your TFS build, the bits and binaries will be deployed to your target server directly.